# IOException Java

Tags: java, exception

I tried to run this piece of code without an internet connection, expecting and IOException to trigger:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class API_connect {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL API = new URL("http://api.football-data.org");
            URLConnection API_connection = API.openConnection();
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException exception) {
            System.out.print(exception);
        }
        catch(IOException exception) {
            System.out.print(exception);
            System.out.print("is something going on here?");
        }                   
    }

}
```

And well... To my surprise nothing was printed, and I can't figure out why. Wouldn't a lack of internet connection be the main reason why an IOException is thrown here?

Comment: When printing exceptions I generally prefer to use [printStackTrace()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace--)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`openConnection()` does not actually try to connect:

> It should be noted that a URLConnection instance does not establish the actual network connection on creation. This will happen only when calling URLConnection.connect().

Try calling `connect()` on it.

Alternatively, you could try the following:

```
new URL(...).openStream().read();
```

That would actually try to read 1 byte from that url and would fail.

Comment: I would add, he opens a connection, but not getting and outputing anything from that connection. Meaning: It works and you need to get and write something from that connection. Sometimes nothing is the best that can happen. In your code. You can't get any output if it works correctly.

Comment: I think, the OP was expecting some exception on a connection attempt. Both `connect()` and `read()` would produce an exception.

Comment: That did infact trigger the exception, thanks. Now I'm curious however as to why openConnection() would throw an IOException. If being offline doesn't trigger it, what would?

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy probably should make my own thread for this. But why does `connect()` and `read()` throw an exception?

Comment: `openConnection()` is defined in `URL` class that is not specific to only HTTP (where it may be costly to 'connect right away', but it can be used with `file:` protocol where 'a connection right away' makes sense. So I believe that the designers of `openConnection()` method allowed it throw an `IOException` to give it more flexibility (in regard with different implementations).

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy so it throws if it can't connect... Then we have the solution for the OP aswell

Comment: @Sens `connect()` and `read()` try to establish an actual connection, and that attempt fails with no Internet, of course.